# Change previous-text and next-text from Pager (Angular & UI-Bootstrap)

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, pager

I want to change the button texts from Pager UI-Bootstrap in Angular.

I've this array:

```
categories = ["Standard", "Premium"];
```

But this code show the variable's name and with moustache doesn't work.

```
<uib-pager total-items="categories.length" items-per-page=1 ng-model="page" previous-text=categories[page-2] next-text=categories[page] ></uib-pager>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works but I would prefer use uib-pager:

```
<ul class="pager">
        <li class="previous" ng-class="{'disabled':!categories[pag-2]}" ng-click="pag=pag-1"><a href="">{{categories[pag-2]}}</a></li>
        <li class="next" ng-class="{'disabled':!categories[pag]}" ng-click="pag=pag+1"><a href="">{{categories[pag]}}</a></li>
</ul>
```